# GET file Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I failed to update mp3 file to my audio tag

*GET 
http://localhost:3000/songs/Jason_Shaw-Running_Waters.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]*

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
var config = require('./webpack.config')

var app = new (require('express'))()
var port = 3000

var compiler = webpack(config)
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }))
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler))

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  } else {
    console.info("Open up http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", port, port)
  }
})
```

Could you explain me how I need to edit my server.js file in order to achieve appropriate result. Do I need to add any loader(s) to my webpack.config.js for the mp3 files ?

Comment: What part of your code do you think is supposed to be making a route for `/songs/Jason_Shaw-Running_Waters.mp3`?  Is there something related to that file or directory in `webpack.config`?

Comment: there's nothing about that directory in webpack.config. Should I have something like that:      test:   /\.mp3$/,  path.resolve(__dirname, "src") ??

Comment: node.js does not serve ANY files by default.  So, if you expect to serve files from the `/songs` directory, then you need a route to handle that.  Probably you want something like `app.use("/songs", express.static("/songs"))`, but you need to tune both paths according to what exactly you're trying to do and where the songs are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from some talented person!

```
app.use('/songs', express.static(__dirname + '/songs'));
```

YEAH!